# How to test if a directory exists

Tags: macros, filesystem-access, folders

The command `\IfFileExists` works great to test if a file exists. Is there an equivalent to test if a directory exists?  `\IfFileExists` does not seem to work for directories.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\ExistingDirName}{./ExistingDir}%       This exists
\newcommand*{\NonExistingDirName}{./NonExistingDir}% This does not exist

\newcommand*{\ExistingFileName}{\ExistingDirName/ExistingFile.tex}% This exists
\newcommand*{\NonExistingFileName}{NonExistingFile.tex}% This does not exist


\newcommand*{\CheckExistence}[1]{
    \IfFileExists{#1}{
        "#1" exists\par
    }{
        "#1" does NOT exist\par
    }
}

\CheckExistence{\ExistingDirName}%    incorrect results
\CheckExistence{\NonExistingDirName}% correct result

\bigskip
\CheckExistence{\ExistingFileName}%    works
\CheckExistence{\NonExistingFileName}% works

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\IfFileExists` uses the TeX facility for reading a file line by line: it tries to open it for line by line reading and issues success or failure. There are two catches: (1) if a file name is given without extension, `.tex` is added; (2) the operating system won't allow to read a directory, which is not a readable file.

Comment: +1 for a good question. Sorry, but I don't have an answer; I was just about to ask this same question myself!

Comment: Hey is a solution, but it is ugly, suboptimal, kludgy, and insecure -- so just a comment, not a solution. Just `\immediate\write18{touch \testdir/bogus_file}` and then use `\IfFileExists` on the newly-created bogus_file. And then delete it with another write18.

Comment: Interesting idea... But, I am trying to avoid OS specific functions.

Comment: @Peter Unfortunately, testing the existence of a directory *is* OS specific.

Comment: Yes it is OS specific, but there should be a macro that handles any OS differences (well at least for Unix OS (Mac) and Windows)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As egreg said there is no direct test for directories. One possibility is if you are trying to read a file from within a directory then use `\IfFileExists` to check for its existence. If you are trying to write a file in the directory, then just try to open it for writing using `\immediate\openout`.

If you're not trying to read or write a file in the directory then the presence of the directory is unlikely to matter much (unless you just wish to do something different based on whether it is there or not) as you cannot enumerate directories without invoking the shell.

Comment: Looks like there is not a good solution to this at this time. I wanted to have different behavior depending on if a directory exists or not.  Will try @David's suggestion.

Comment: @PeterGrill I am not sure why you marked this as the answer (no offense TH.) because it does not address how to test for a directory. This answer tests for a file if I understood it correctly as you have already demonstrated in your question.

Comment: @macmadness86: You make a good point, but I think "there is no direct test for directories" qualifes as an answer. You can invoke the shell to test for a directory, but there is nothing built into TeX to solve this issue.

Comment: @PeterGrill I guess I missed the opening sentence: "[...] there is no direct test for directories. " Bummer.

Comment: "If you are trying to write a file in the directory, then just try to open it ": how would you catch the error if the writing fails? For instance to run a mkdir command in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is a pretty old thread. I fixed the problem by adding a sample text file in my TeX directory and used `\IfFileExists` to check for the existence of that text file. This method is OS independent. It is not a super smart way, at least does the job!